# How to display images of products with respect to products id in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 10 images of each brand and want to display brand by brand with there press releases images.

**Example:**

```
    Product 1:
    press release_image1,press release_image2,press release_image3 so on..
    Product 2:
    press release_image1,press release_image2,press release_image3 so on..
    Product 3:
    press release_image1,press release_image2,press release_image3 so on..
```

Comment: And what? Did you write some code?

Comment: are they foreign key linked?

Comment: Yes foreign key in linked

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($press as $p){ ?>
                                <div class="header">
                                    <h1 class=''>
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/brand/view')."/".$p->brand_id;?>">
                                            <?php
                                                echo $p->brand_name;
                                            ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </h1>
                                </div>

                                <section id="portfolio-preview-items" class="row four-cols rows_1">
                                        <?php //$row = $this->dashboard->get_press_release($id);
                                       ?>
                                        <!-- Portfolio Normal Mode -->
                                        <div class="portfolio-item design web-design  v3" data-id="354" style="height: 475px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                            <div class="he-wrap tpl2">
                                                <a href="<?php echo base_url('assets/files/press_release') . '/' . $p->press_image; ?>" class="image-614" data-lightbox="event_img" data-title="<?php echo $p->press_title; ?>" >
                                                    <img style="cursor:pointer;" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/files/press_release') . '/' . $p->press_image; ?>" alt="">
                                                </a>
                                                <div class="shape4"></div>
                                                <div class="he-view">
                                                    <div class="bg a0" data-animate="fadeIn">
                                                        <div class="center-bar v1">
                                                            <a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/brand/view').'/'.$p->brand_id; ?>" class="link a0" data-animate="zoomIn">
                                                                <i class="moon-link-4"></i>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Portfolio Normal Mode End -->

                                </section>
                                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: what is image table name

Comment: There are two tables brands and press_release, and images will be fetch from press_release by brand_id

Answer (score 0):

You can combine id and particular images(concat by ',') from mysql query.
then in php code u can use explode and implode to display each images